# How to get dynamic value in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Form Validation Example</h2>
<form name="myForm" novalidate="novalidate" data-ng-app="myapp" data-ng-controller="myc">

<p>User Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="fname" data-ng-minlength="10" data-ng-required="true" placeholder="Enter name" class="myname">

</p>

<p>Email:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail" ng-click="click($event)" data-ng-model="mail" data-ng-required="true" class="mymail" placeholder="enter mail id"/>

</p>

 <input type="submit" value="click" ng-click="click()" />

  </form>

<script src="angularjs/angular.js"></script>

<script>
var app =angular.module("myapp",[]);

app.controller('myc',function($scope)
        {   
            var fname=$scope.fname;
            $scope.click = function()
            {
                console.log("name "+fname);
                alert("name "+fname);
            }

        });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to get a value which is entered by the user and after that I want to display it in the browser.

I don't want to set the value using `$scope` inside the controller.
I tried many times but I was unsuccessful to do it. 
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the `ng-model` in click handler function as a parameter.

```
<input type="text" name="mail" data-ng-model="mail" data-ng-required="true" class="mymail" placeholder="enter mail id"/>

<input type="submit" value="click" ng-click="click(mail)" />
```

Show the model value in alert as

```
 $scope.click = function(mail)
    {
        console.log("mail "+mail);
        alert("mail "+mail);
    }
```

Comment: when i clicked on input text filed it displayed undefined.

Comment: @vickykumarjaiswal type something and then click.

Comment: i wanted to do so but but when ever i enter into textField it generate event and display undefine.event should be triggered when i click on click button.